# Почему не изменяются свойства префаба?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, prefabs

Такая проблема: из скрипта я изменяю картинку спрайта компонента SpriteRenderer (типо другой скин) в неком префабе, имея ссылку на SpriteRenderer. И проблема в том, что когда я запускаю игру в юнити, все работает, т.е. скин меняется. А когда я запускаю это в билде (apk файл), то скин не меняется. Почему так?

Код элементарный, приведу отрывок:

```
[SerializeField] SpriteRenderer player; //в инспекторе на это поле я перетаскиваю префаб игрока
[SerializeField] Sprite[] skins; // сюда перетаскиваю картинки игрока (скины)
int i = Random.Range(0, skins.Length);
player.sprite = skins[i]; // так я назначаю скин игроку
```

Comment: Такая же проблема была когда я думал с помощью префабов реализовать светлую и тёмную тему. Предполагаю что в готовом apk файле отсутствует поле префабов.

Comment: Печально если так, но блин, неужели разработчикам сложно было сделать это?

Comment: Не думаю что они поленились сделать такое поле. Может оно есть но по другому называется / используется.